# Boundedness and closedness properties in euclidian space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Every undergrad knows that in (finite dimensional) euclidian space "compactness=boundedness+closedness". I've been thinking: if we're given a connected, bounded, but neither closed nor open subset A of euclidian space is it always possible to find a closed but not bounded subset B (different from whole space) in the same space, s.t. there is a homeomorphism between them? (I.e. can we interchange these properties?) That seems very wrong, but I wasn't able to come up with a concrete example of subset, s.t. it is impossible. I know that A can't be open, because of the Brouwer's theorem, also if A has only one bounady point NOT in it, then we can always perform an inversion centered at that point, to get the desired set B. Can somebody please ruin my dreams with an example where it is (more or less) obviously impossible?

Comment: Actually, I can: take a euclidian plane and take any open interval on any axis. It's not closed, but bounded. It is homeomorphic to the whole axis, which is closed, but not bounded.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that you wanted to find a homeomorphism from the whole space into itself, which maps $A$ to $B$.

Comment: I have a problem understanding your question. You write you know that $A$ cannot be open (aside, if $A$ is homeomorphic to the whole space, e.g. if $A$ is a ball, then there is a closed unbounded $B$ homeomorphic to $A$), so that would answer your question, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes, you're right, I should've written it "neither closed, nor open".

Comment: Every closed subset of a Euclidean space is $\sigma$-compact, and $\sigma$-compactness is preserved by homeomorphisms. So take a bounded set $A$ that is not $\sigma$-compact.

Answer (score 1):

Any connected open set $U$ "almost" works: Any homeomorphic image $f(U)$ on the same Euclidean space has to be open (this result is called invariance of domain). The only issue is that $f(U)$ could be the entire space, which is the only open and closed set (not counting the empty set). So we only have to construct an connected open set that's not homeomorphic to the entire space; for instance in dimension 2 you can take the annulus $U=\{ x:  1<|x|<2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should've mentioned explicitly, that I don't consider the case, where B is the whole space.

Comment: @МарияАвророва: Then any open set $U$ works!

Comment: But you've written yourself that by invariance of domain the image B must be open

Comment: @МарияАвророва: Ah, I see you want $A$ neither open nor closed. It also seems you already knew this $A$ open case. Let me think a bit more.